# highest , lowest , and and the answer when subtracted in java

Tags: java, loops, highest

Write a program that accepts as many integers the user wants to input. Determine the highest and lowest numbers and subtract all other numbers from the highest number. I can't get the difference. I know there's missing here. please help me.

```
import java.util.*;
//Misty Stewart
public class HighestLowestDifference2324 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double minValue1 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double minValue2 = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int count = 0;
        double difference = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter numbers. Terminate with Q.");
        while (input.hasNextDouble()) {

            double Value = input.nextDouble();

            if (Value > maxValue) {
                maxValue = Value;
            }
            if (Value < minValue) {
                minValue = Value;
            }
            if (Value < minValue) {
                minValue1 = Value;
            }
            if (minValue == minValue1) {
                minValue = Value;
            }
            if (Value < minValue1) {
                minValue2 = Value;
            }
            if (minValue1 == minValue2) {
                minValue1 = Value;
            }
        }
        count++;
        difference = maxValue - minValue;
        {
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Highest no. is: " + maxValue);
                System.out.println("Lowest no. is: " + minValue);
                System.out.println("The difference from the highest is: \n" + difference);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Have a good day!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: example: 15,20,29,38,12,42
Output:
Highest: 42
Lowest:12
[The difference from the highest is:
[42-15]=27
[42-20]=22
[42-29]=13
[42-38]=4
[42-312]=30

.. please help me.thanks

Comment: Is there a problem? You can use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to clean out the code a bit

Comment: There is an assignment and some code. There is something missing: a question!

Comment: what is the difference?,,that's the question

Comment: when i used 0, it only returned the highest value

Comment: What's the difference between **what** and **what**? Please ask a coherent, relevant question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Double> allValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value);
        minValue = Math.min(minValue, value);

        allValues.add(value);
    }

    System.out.println("Highest no. is: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("Lowest no. is: " + minValue);
    System.out.println("The difference from the highest is:" + (maxValue - minValue));
    for (Double value : allValues) {
        System.out.println("The difference from the highest is:" + (maxValue - value));
    }
```

Comment: thanks..it's too close!! ^_^... but still there's something wrong..

Comment: sir sean, if i enter numbers: 15, 20, 29, 38,12, 42... it shows: 30,27, 22,13,4,30,0

Comment: accrdg. to my professor it must only be: 27,22,13,4,30.. Only one 30 and no zero.. because 42-15=27; 42-20=22; 42-29=13; 42-38=4; 42-12=30

Comment: :-) good, I'm glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the values entered by the user in an array. And then once you have the `maxVAlue`, iterate over the array with a loop and calculate and display the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
 num = input.nextDouble();
 if ( num > max ) max = num;
 if ( num < min ) min = num;
}

difference = max -min;
```

above code can be used to get the highest , lowest , and their difference from list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store all the input numbers in a `Collection`, for example an `ArrayList`, and do your analysis afterwards:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
  double value = input.nextDouble();

  // logic for determining largest & smallest

  list.add(value);
}
```

And afterwards iterate over the `ArrayList` to get your desired output.

Comment: sir blagae, can you pls. add that to my code and show it off?...

Comment: i dont't know how to do array, eh?..please. ^_^